# Need help making sense of this poem

Tags: grammar

> 鳴神の 少し響みて さし曇り 雨も降らぬか 君を留めむ

Heard this in a movie.
Really can't make sense of this grammar, to be honest. Can anybody break down what's going on here?

Thanks :)

Comment: It appears to be in Classical Japanese.

Comment: I know some classical Japanese but I'm still having difficulties understanding this. It's a poem, which makes things even harder.

Comment: It's from the [万葉集, 11-2513](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man11Yo.html): 雷神 小動 刺雲 雨零耶 君将留, transcribed as *naru kamwi no sukosi toyomite sasi-kumori ame mo pura-nu ka kimi wo todome-mu* in the [OCOJ](http://vsarpj.orinst.ox.ac.uk/corpus/texts.html).

Comment: Oh, it's a duplicate? I didn't notice. Probably because of the different writing.
Thanks @snailboat

I would still love an explanation of the grammar here, if possible.

Comment: You haven't really asked anything specific about the grammar.  Do you have a specific question?  You can start by comparing with user4092's translation into Modern Japanese, and look up things you don't understand in a 古語辞典, and then ask again if you have a more specific question about something you still don't get.  How's that sound?

Comment: There's a freely available 古語辞典 at Weblio: http://kobun.weblio.jp/